# Find the matrix representing a reflection in the line $y=2x-2$

Tags: matrices, geometry

I need to find the matrix representing reflection in the line $y=2x-2$.

I wanted to change variables to $X=x$ and $Y=y+2$ and then proceed as normal to find the reflection matrix in $Y=2X$. But then I didn't know how to change the variables back to $x, y$ in the matrix.
I got the matrix to be:
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 2.4 \\
1 & -0.2 \\
\end{pmatrix}
But I think this is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ordinarily, matrices are used for linear maps. Linear maps take $(0,0)$ to itself, so they can't describe this map. There are two ways you could get around this:

(1) You can write the map in the form
$$\begin{bmatrix} x\\y \end{bmatrix} \longrightarrow \begin{bmatrix} a&b \\ c&d \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x\\y \end{bmatrix}  + \begin{bmatrix} e\\f \end{bmatrix}$$
for some constants $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$, $f$.

I don't want to do a homework problem, so I'll answer a different question: Let's think about rotation of $60^{\circ}$ counterclockwise around the point $(2,3)$. As you suggest, make the change of variables $(X,Y) = (x-2, y-3)$. The matrix of the rotation in $(X,Y)$ coordinates is $\left[ \begin{smallmatrix} 1/2 & -\sqrt{3}/2 \\ \sqrt{3}/2 & 1/2 \\ \end{smallmatrix} \right]$. In $(x,y)$ coordinates, we have
$$\begin{bmatrix} x\\y \end{bmatrix} \longrightarrow \begin{bmatrix} 1/2 & - \sqrt{3}/2 \\ \sqrt{3}/2 & 1/2 \\ \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x-2 \\ y-3 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 2\\3 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1/2 & - \sqrt{3}/2 \\ \sqrt{3}/2 & 1/2 \\ \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x\\y \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 1+3 \sqrt{3}/2 \\ 3/2 - \sqrt{3} \end{bmatrix}.$$

(2) The group of rigid symmetries of the plane can be described with $3 \times 3$ matrices: Describe the symmetry $\vec{x} \mapsto Q \vec{x} + \vec{b}$ by the $3 \times 3$ block matrix
$$\left[ \begin{array}{c|c}  Q & \vec{b} \\ \hline  0 & 1 \end{array} \right] .$$
This group preserves the set of vectors of the form $(x,y,1)$, and acts on them by rigid motions. So, inside this group, we can use the usual conjugation formula to change coordinates. Repeating my examples of a $60^{\circ}$ rotation around $(2,3)$, we get
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&2 \\ 0&1&3 \\ 0&0&1 \\ \end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} 1/2 & - \sqrt{3}/2 & 0 \\ \sqrt{3}/2 & 1/2 & 0 \\ 0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&2 \\ 0&1&3 \\ 0&0&1 \\ \end{bmatrix}^{-1} =
\begin{bmatrix} 1/2 & - \sqrt{3}/2 & 1+3 \sqrt{3}/2 \\ \sqrt{3}/2 & 1/2 & 3/2-\sqrt{3} \\ 0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 2):

**Generally speaking:**

A reflection can be thought of as a composition of the following transformations:

1. Shifting plane such that the line passes through origin
2. Rotating the line onto the x-axis
3. Reflecting across the x-axis
4. Rotating the line back to it's original position
5. Unshifting the line

You can't really model translations using matrices as far as I know and hence you can't directly do this reflection procedure.

---

**On the attempt you've made and how to modify it to get the correct result:**

The shifts you used are wrong since in the shifted co-ordinate system the line actually doesn't pass through the origin for the shifts which you have used. Instead, follow this procedure,

**(1)** use the shift of $Y=y-2$

**(2)** then use the rotation matrix to transform our 'vector' (*)

**(3)** switch sign-on $y$ component

**(4)** undo the rotation of our point using the rotation matrix of the opposite angle

**(5)** use the inverse transformation of the shift you used on the final point which you got.

Refer [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3755357/using-complex-numbers-to-find-reflections) which I posted where I used complex numbers to achieve the same result

---

*: The point can be described by vectors by considering the position vector connecting to it from the origin.

Answer (score 1):

The image  $(x',y')$  of a point $(x,y)$ in the line $ax+by+c=0$ is given as
$$\frac{x'-x}{a}=\frac{y'-y}{b}=-2\frac{ax+by+c}{a^2+b^2}$$
So here in this case we have
$$\frac{x'-x}{2}=\frac{y'-y}{-1}=-2\frac{2x-y-2}{5}$$
$$\implies x'=(1/5)x+(2/5)y+4/5, y'=(4/5)x+(3/5)y-(4/5).$$
In the matrix notation
$$\begin{bmatrix} x'\\y' \\1 \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 1/5 & 2/5 & 4/5 \\ 4/5 & 3/5 &-4/5\\ 0 & 0& 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x\\y \\1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a point $P(X,Y)$

Now, the mirror is a line with direction cosine $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}},\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}})$ - hence the normal will have direction - $(\frac{2}{\sqrt 5}, -\frac{1}{\sqrt 5})$

Also, the distance $d$ of the point from the mirror is given as

$$d = \frac{|2X-Y-2|}{\sqrt5}$$

Hence, the reflection is given as

$$P' = \left(X +\frac{4d}{\sqrt 5} , Y - \frac{2d}{\sqrt 5}\right)$$

As you can probably see, this cannot be represented as a matrix  multiplication - but also has an extra constant component

Comment: I have two complaints about this answer. The minor one is that you don't want an absolute value in the formula for $d$ -- if $(x,y)$ is on the other side of the mirror, then $d$ should be negative. More subjectively, I think this is a confusing way to write the formula -- it makes it look like $d$ is a constant, but in fact $d$ depends on $X$ and $Y$.